# Is there a way to change all TextViews in Android?

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm attempting to make my textView invisible for 4 seconds and then appear after using the code:

```
final TextView textView233 = findViewById(R.id.textView233);
    textView233.setText("Loading data...");
    textView233.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView233.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }, 4000);
```

In the situation where I have over 100 textViews in my activity and I want ALL textviews to do the same, is there a way to apply it to all textViews other than writing the code for all 100 of them? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Use an `Array` of `TextView`

Answer (score 2):

add all these TextView inside some LinearLayout and hide the LinearLayout layout after the given internal instead of hiding each and every TextView separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a custom class:

**AnimTextView.java**

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class AnimTextView {

private ArrayList<TextView> textViewList;

public AnimTextView(TextView ... textViews) {
    textViewList = new ArrayList<>();
    textViewList.addAll(Arrays.asList(textViews));
}

public void startLoading(){
    for (final TextView textView: textViewList) {
        textView.setText("Loading data...");
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }, 4000);
    }
}
}
```

Now, In your Main Activity:

```
AnimTextView animTextView = new AnimTextView(textView1, textView2, textView3, textView4, ...);
```

And when you need to start loading:

```
animTextView.startLoading();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is function that will get all TextViews of the Activity(even nested) and hide, you can call it from your **Handler**:

```
fun recursiveHideTextAllViews(parent: ViewGroup?) {
    for (i in 0 until parent!!.childCount) {
        val child: View? = parent.getChildAt(i)
        if (child is ViewGroup) {
            recursiveHideTextAllViews(child as ViewGroup?)
        } else if (child!!.javaClass == AppCompatTextView::class.java) {
            child.visibility = View.INVISIBLE;
        }
    }
}
```

**parent** is your Root view